# Unable to execute a nested template in desired order which further rollback

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, nested, aws-cloudformation

I need advice from you all as I am in stuck in a production level deployment.

I have a master template that deploys (in sequence) Roles, Security groups, LB(listeners/target groups) and finally ECS (ECS on spot fleet). All these above are separate templates which are pulled by the master template (AWS::CloudFormation::Stack) from TemplateURL s3.

When I keep both ECS resources and Spot fleet on the same template I am able to deploy the full cluster and complete stack gets created. But now the client wants the ECS and SPOT instance template to be separated as well. Now we have the templates for Roles, Security Groups, ALB, ECS and Spot deployed through a master template. Cloud formation creates ALB, Roles, Security groups successfully but then starts working on ECS template and when it comes to creating service for ECS the template stucks in CREATE IN PROGRESS. (Service Event Error: No container instances found for the cluster). I can understand that this is because spot fleet is not deployed yet by the other template for spot and hence service is not getting created.

Do we have any way to launch the spot fleet first (through its template) and then the ECS service/tasks etc. (through its template). Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding DependsOn condition in your template ? this will make sure that all the required resources are created first and then ECS resource is created